# Dowload file from Server

Tags: webclient, server.mappath

How I can download a file from a server using WebClient ad Server.MapPath and dowload it to Desktop?
Example:

```
 WebClient Client= nre WebClient();
 Client.DownloadFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/")+fileRoute,@"~/Desktop/"+fileName);
```